# Subscriptions in Stripe - if a subscription payment didn't pan out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm working on a Rails app where I'm using stripe for creating subscriptions. Suppose, the first month the user has been charged successfully but on the second month their bank card got expired or ran out of money and they, obviously, weren't charged. How would I, as an admin of that Rails app, know if such the case has happened with one of my users?

Answer (score 0):

Check api for callback after payment process, there must be something which would notify your app regarding payment(if it was succesfull or failure), and afterwards do some actions.

Comment: there must be isn't helpful.